# fabric.js extend fabric.Image.prototype_render subclass

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I just want to add custom label property to existing Image object with _render .
fabric.Image.prototype has _render  method so i have copied from fabric.js library and overridden it as

```
       fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Image.prototype, {

           _render: function(ctx, noTransform) {
           var x, y, imageMargins = this._findMargins(), elementToDraw;

           x = (noTransform ? this.left : -this.width / 2);
           y = (noTransform ? this.top : -this.height / 2);

           if (this.meetOrSlice === 'slice') {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(x, y, this.width, this.height);
            ctx.clip();
           }

           if (this.isMoving === false && this.resizeFilters.length &&                                              this._needsResize()) {
               this._lastScaleX = this.scaleX;
               this._lastScaleY = this.scaleY;
               elementToDraw = this.applyFilters(null, this.resizeFilters, this._filteredEl || this._originalElement, false);
           }else {
               elementToDraw = this._element;
           }
           elementToDraw && ctx.drawImage(elementToDraw,
                                 x + imageMargins.marginX,
                                 y + imageMargins.marginY,
                                 imageMargins.width,
                                 imageMargins.height
                                );
           this._renderStroke(ctx);  

            // Custom code added
            ctx.font = '12px Ubuntu';
            ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
            ctx.style = '1px dashed';
            ctx.fillText(this.label, this.width/2-10, -(this.height/2) - 10);

        }
   });
```

I am aware this is not the correct way to do as such.
is there a way to extend the current _render function and just add

```
  ctx.font = '12px Ubuntu';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
  ctx.style = '1px dashed';
  ctx.fillText(this.label, this.width/2-10, -(this.height/2) - 10);
```

with  JavaScript prototype inheritance

Any help would be good

Answer (score 0):

In your extended class, add a callSuper in your overriden _render function first, and then add your own code. Like this...

```
_render: function(ctx) {
  this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
  /* your code */
}
```